# Flutter Web App Firebase Hosting Setup Complete Screen Appearance?

Tags: firebase, flutter, hosting

Every time i deploy my flutter web app to firebase and open the hosting url this welcome screen appears. I have deployed one web app before and it works fine but this time i am not able to host it properly. Is there any solution to it?
Thanks.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you should wait a bit. I have recently noticed that(for me) *.web.app links took longer to sync than *.firebase.app for my flutter website.